# Where are the django folders located after installation?

Tags: django-templates

After installation of django I could not find django templates folder as well as other django files in home drive.

Answer (score -1):

If you have installed Python IDE such as Pycharm  the django folder is located in 
for example `Python34\Lib\site-packages\django`.